# Primefaces (6.0) fileuploadlistener not fired in nested table

Tags: primefaces, nested

I am not sure if it is supported as I cannot make the fileUploadListener working in the subTable. Only the basic file upload demo works in the nested table. Seems like the FileUploadEvent is not called. Upload progress bar shows and disappears but the listener method is not fired.

```
<p:dataTable var="parent" value="#{bean.parents}">    
  <p:columnGroup type="header">
    <p:row>
      <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Parent name</f:facet>
      </p:column>
      <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Child name</f:facet>
      </p:column>
      <p:column headerText="Actions"/>
    </p:row>
  </p:columnGroup>

  <p:subTable var="child" value="#{parent.children}">
    <f:facet name="header">#{parent.name}</f:facet>
    <p:column>#{child.name}</p:column>
    <p:column>
      <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{bean.handleFileUpload}"/>
    </p:column>
  </p:subTable>

</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: why not use it as a dialog ?!?

Comment: read this post to learn how to upload a file [How to upload a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486157/get-uploaded-file-path-in-primefaces/39487964#39487964)